# How to trigger event from parent component to modal child componet

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

In my angular project I am using BsModalRef bootstrap library for Modal Window.

To pass data from parent to child component I have used initial state object.

Like Below

```
const initialState = {
  modalTitle: "Transfer In",
};
    
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(TestModalComponent, {
                 initialState,
                });
```

Its working fine.

But I need to trigger event from my parent component to modal child component.

Is there any way to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What event do you have to trigger and why? A modal grabs user focus, so what reason can the parent component have to trigger an event in the modal? Unless that event is based on a timer, and then you can simply activate the time inside the model component.

Comment: Hi Aviad, I need to show the same modal with progress percentage. So I am closing and opening the modal again.  After displaying modal I don't know how to update that child component value.so I planned to do this way